# How can i set a programmatically created view to tab?

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I am getting the error:

> 05-14 15:06:13.124:
>   ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2218): Caused by:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not
>   create tab content because could not
>   find view with id 123

Why can i not do something like this? What am i missing? Here is the code, basically an RSSview is an extended scrollview with a table layout and rss processor (built programmatically)

```
    final BrRSSView newsView = new BrRSSView(currentActivity,rss);
    newsView.setId(123); 

    tabHost.addTab(
            tabHost.newTabSpec("tab1")
            .setIndicator("Nyheter", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icons_tab_nyheter))
            .setContent(123));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that the `TabHost` only looks for the view id  *inside* the `tabcontent` view. If you still want to do this via code, you can add your view to the `tabcontent` view and then run the `addTab()` method.

Comment: Ahh, ok that makes sense, but i do not know how to do it. There is an XML view called view1 that is assigned to tab 1 but it crashes if i try to do:
((ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.view1)).addView(newsView);

Comment: Question, Why aren't you declaring the BrRSSView directly in the tab's XML? This will save you a lot of headaches. Also, I should note that whatever you pass to the `TabSpec`'s `setContent()` has to be a *direct child* of the `tabcontent` view.

Comment: It has to be dynamic and because it is for an in-house toolkit. Plus it may not always be used in tabs..

Comment: Great i got it now, i had to add the view to the tabhost first.